# Выполнения строкового выражения в ПХП

Tags: php, html

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть див,туда вывожу через нажатие кнопок числа,записывается это все как строка.
Каким способом можно просчитать выражение в этой строке,допустим.

> 8*2/5+2

Пока на ум приходит,перебирать через цикл и если встречается какой то знак,выполнять соответсвующее действие
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем заранее спасибо за советы и ответы :3

Comment: Обратная польская запись?)

Comment: я одного понять не могу: Див, кнопки... **При чем тут РНР?**

Comment: @Ипатьев как можно через пхп просчитать,что написано в диве?
я через $_POST передаю значения,но хз как посчитать эту строку

Comment: ЗАЧЕМ передавать в РНР, считать там, и потом передавать обратно? какой смысл гонять эту несчастную строку туда-сюда?

Comment: Действительно, почему бы на JS не считать?

Comment: @Ипатьев такое задание,через аджакс передать в пхп)

Comment: @AntonZikov Такое задание)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18880821/7185813 - тут есть пример под заголовком "A better solution would be..."

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval):

```
$ma ="8*2/5+2";
$p = eval('return '.$ma.';');
print $p;
```

Comment: Всегда можно быть уверенным что напишут этот дебильный ответ

Comment: @Ипатьев он неправильный?

Comment: eval опасная штука...

Comment: В примере по ссылке есть другие. В конечном итоге человек сам решит каким ему пользоваться.